# Regex to find valid url + text python only

Tags: python, regex, validation, url, expression

I have a regex

```
((http\://|https\://|ftp\://)|(www.)|([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\?\.'~#-]*)?
```

which is picking valid url perfectly.

I have a scenario where there can be

1. VALID URL + TEXT or (www.abc.com testing the regex)
2. Text + VALID URL (Testing the regex www.abc.com)

REQ:

What i want is first the regex check the valid url then if url is valid it ignores the Valid url and search TEXT only outside the Valid URL.

Issues:

I have tried many regex but it is picking the valid url also which i don't want i only want if url is valid search for the text outside the url.

NO function Please . I am trying to fix this using Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want this:

```
(.*?)((?:(?:http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/|ftp\:\/\/)|(?:www.)|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]))+(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9%:\/-_\?\.'~#-]*)?)(.*)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/OdZpIsBfwJ) here:

You will get three groups, you can used named groups to catpure `beforeUrl` text, `Url` and `afterUrl` text, which will be something like this:

```
(?<beforeUrl>.*?)(?<Url>(?:(?:http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/|ftp\:\/\/)|(?:www.)|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]))+(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9%:\/-_\?\.'~#-]*)?)(?<afterUrl>.*)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/paB35d7X9d) here.

Comment: Thanks. This looks great. I'll try this and see if it is not missing any validation i want.

Comment: ok i have tried this but it is giving all the things. I just want those textboxes which have valid + text or text + valid url. At the moment it is giving me those textboxes also which just have Valid URL.

Comment: need to bind valid url + text and text + valid url. other than that regex ignore them.

Comment: it is behaving same as the previous regex. All is good but need to ignore valid url  if www.abc.com is provided.

Comment: ^(((http\://|https\://|ftp\://)|(www.)|([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9%:/-_\?\.'~#-&-+.!,()|]*)?)$

This trick work. This is only getting Valid url. Thanks.